# It's not setting the state for comments post in a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, polymorphism

I'm trying to put some state on my comments post who was created with polymorphic association.
in my app/controllers/posts/comments_controller.rb

```
class Posts::CommentsController < CommentsController
  before_action :set_commentable
  #after_create :set_post_state

  private

  def set_commentable
    @commentable = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    set_post_state
    debugger
  end

  def set_post_state
    @commentable.update(state_id: params[:state_id])
  end
end
```

As you can see I'm debugging for watch if the state_id was updated and it wasn't.

```
Started POST "/posts/2/comments" for ::1 at 2018-03-19 13:42:10 +0100
Processing by Posts::CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2AqfjRll/e7FVbnhZTA1DroG1pDPhdpqoiifLJkrIs6zqlmJnTuVVDIu7g0Bsh0L11dfzc/pbQVzdTJvZc0HUg==", "comment"=>{"content"=>"test", "state_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "post_id"=>"2"}
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
  Post Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts"."title" = 'Internet Explorer' AND "posts"."id" != 2) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Return value is: nil

[6, 15] in /Users/romenigld/ror_workspace/projects/news_city/app/controllers/posts/comments_controller.rb
    6:
    7:   def set_commentable
    8:     @commentable = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    9:     set_post_state
   10:     debugger
=> 11:   end
   12:
   13:   def set_post_state
   14:     @commentable.update(state_id: params[:state_id])
   15:   end
(byebug) ap @commentable
/Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@rails4.2.8/gems/awesome_print-1.7.0/lib/awesome_print/formatters/base_formatter.rb:31: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
#<Post:0x007fd03266b958> {
            :id => 2,
         :title => "Internet Explorer",
      :subtitle => "My sample of the subtitle",
       :content => "A sample post about Internet Explorer",
    :created_at => Mon, 12 Mar 2018 16:18:28 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Mon, 12 Mar 2018 16:18:28 UTC +00:00,
     :author_id => 1,
    :attachment => #<AttachmentUploader:0x007fd0326602d8 @model=#<Post id: 2, title: "Internet Explorer", subtitle: "My sample of the subtitle", content: "A sample post about Internet Explorer", created_at: "2018-03-12 16:18:28", updated_at: "2018-03-12 16:18:28", author_id: 1, attachment: "attachment.jpeg", state_id: nil>, @mounted_as=:attachment, @storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::File:0x007fd032660148 @uploader=#<AttachmentUploader:0x007fd0326602d8 ...>>, @file=#<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x007fd03265b288 @file="/Users/romenigld/ror_workspace/projects/news_city/public/uploads/post/attachment/2/attachment.jpeg", @original_filename=nil, @content_type=nil>, @versions={:thumb=>#<AttachmentUploader::Uploader70266096198580:0x007fd03265b1c0 @model=#<Post id: 2, title: "Internet Explorer", subtitle: "My sample of the subtitle", content: "A sample post about Internet Explorer", created_at: "2018-03-12 16:18:28", updated_at: "2018-03-12 16:18:28", author_id: 1, attachment: "attachment.jpeg", state_id: nil>, @mounted_as=:attachment, @parent_version=#<AttachmentUploader:0x007fd0326602d8 ...>, @storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::File:0x007fd03265b008 @uploader=#<AttachmentUploader::Uploader70266096198580:0x007fd03265b1c0 ...>>, @file=#<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x007fd032659fc8 @file="/Users/romenigld/ror_workspace/projects/news_city/public/uploads/post/attachment/2/thumb_attachment.jpeg", @original_filename=nil, @content_type=nil>, @versions={}>, :small_thumb=>#<AttachmentUploader::Uploader70266096186560:0x007fd03265b198 @model=#<Post id: 2, title: "Internet Explorer", subtitle: "My sample of the subtitle", content: "A sample post about Internet Explorer", created_at: "2018-03-12 16:18:28", updated_at: "2018-03-12 16:18:28", author_id: 1, attachment: "attachment.jpeg", state_id: nil>, @mounted_as=:attachment, @parent_version=#<AttachmentUploader:0x007fd0326602d8 ...>, @storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::File:0x007fd032659d70 @uploader=#<AttachmentUploader::Uploader70266096186560:0x007fd03265b198 ...>>, @file=#<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x007fd032658cb8 @file="/Users/romenigld/ror_workspace/projects/news_city/public/uploads/post/attachment/2/small_thumb_attachment.jpeg", @original_filename=nil, @content_type=nil>, @versions={}>}>,
      :state_id => nil
}
nil
(byebug)
```

in `app/controllers/comments_controller.rb` I add:

```
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :state_id)
  end
```

app/models/comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :state
```

app/models/post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :state

  has_many :roles, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
```

app/models/state.rb

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base

  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `params[:state_id]` is nil but better not guess and instead put a `puts` just before the update and check it out yourself:

`13:   def set_post_state
   -->     puts "Params: #{params}"
   14:     @commentable.update(state_id: params[:state_id])
   15:   end`

Comment: Hello @draganstankovic I do this and was:
Params: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "comment"=>{"content"=>"vai", "state_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "controller"=>"posts/comments", "action"=>"create", "post_id"=>"1"}

Answer (score 0):

I put like @draganstankovic put a  `puts "Params: #{params}"`
and then I observe the params was needed to put the comment params like this `params[:comment][:state_id]` and now it's recording.

```
  def set_post_state
    puts "Params: #{params}"
    @commentable.update!(state_id: params[:comment][:state_id])
  end
```

Thank's for reply @draganstankovic.